# Amazon S3 LastModified time vs Upload complete time

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am a bit confused on meaning of LastModified time in S3.
Suppose I start upload of a large file at 10:00 AM and say upload takes 4 minutes. I am seeing that instead of showing LastModified time as 10:04 AM its showing the same as 10:00 AM, i.e. when I initiated the upload.

In Azure Blob Storage however lastModified time however seems to be the time when upload completed.

Am I interpreting this incorrectly for S3 ? I mean how can we have lastModified time as the time when upload starts because technically object is not created until all bytes are uploaded, right ?

Looking at answers like: [amazon S3 upload object LastModified date keep changed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67069033/amazon-s3-upload-object-lastmodified-date-keep-changed) its confusing as they seem to be mentioning LastModified to be the time when upload finished.

Can anyone please confirm ?

Answer (score 1):

`Last-Modified` is defined to be:

> [Object creation date or the last modified date, whichever is the latest.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/UsingMetadata.html#SysMetadata)

Last modified is more like *creation date*, as mentioned in the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/intro-lifecycle-rules.html):

> Amazon S3 maintains only the last modified date for each object. For example, the Amazon S3 console shows the Last Modified date in the object Properties pane. **When you initially create a new object, this date reflects the date the object is created.** If you replace the object, the date changes accordingly. So **when we use the term creation date**, it is **synonymous with the term last modified date**.

It seems that it uses the value of the [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Date) header as demonstrated in the [`PutObject`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_PutObject.html#API_PutObject_Examples) example here - this will be, as you've seen, when the upload request was *started* and not when it *finished*.

Why S3 uses the `Date` header and not the timestamp of when the file has finished uploading is something internal to AWS AFAIK.

I have not seen the answer to the question, "why?" in the docs.

Comment: Regarding PUT there seem to be certain examples (e.g. Example 6: Upload an object and specify tags) in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_PutObject.html#API_PutObject_Examples where request time is different than time in response. Also do we know if this behavior of LastModified have been changed by AWS from start_upload time to end_upload time ?

Comment: I assume this is because the tagging is done **after** the object has been uploaded - try the request. Does it behave the same way or …?